# Jira createmeta endpoint 'issue/createmeta/{project_id}/issuetypes/{issue_type_id} returns empty values list

Tags: python, jira, jira-rest-api

Jira deprecated '/rest/api/2/issue/createmeta' in Jira 9.0 and created a new method for finding issuetypes (specifically custom fields) with the following endpoint

`issue/createmeta/{projectIdOrKey}/issuetypes/{issueTypeId}`

The original request in earlier versions than 8.4 returned a list of custom fields, but having updated to 9.0 and using the new url I get back values: [] for all projects and issue types.

Has anyone run into this?

Answer (score 0):

Does the *[getCreateIssueMetaProjectIssueTypes](https://docs.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/api/REST/8.5.13/#api/2/issue-getCreateIssueMetaProjectIssueTypes)* endpoint:

```
/rest/api/2/issue/createmeta/{projectIdOrKey}/issuetypes
```

return all the issue types for a given project?

Comment: It does, from which I loop through and call the issuetype details endpoint and get nothing returned.

Comment: So, you're saying that the following: */rest/api/2/issue/createmeta/{projectIdOrKey}/issuetypes/10001* returns nothing, and does not contain the information about the issue type Story? Double check you have the latest version of Jira Server and, if so, then you have found a bug and should report it to Atlassian.

Comment: We're currently using version 8.7.0, do you think that needs to be updated to 9.0 and above? Any idea if this would be related to https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirakb/enable-dark-feature-in-jira-959286331.html for versions prior to 8.7? @davidbakkers

Comment: Well, there's part of the problem. You're on 8.7, not 9.0, as per your original post.
The REST API docs for v8.7 says the method for the  getCreateIssueMetaProjectIssueTypes endpoint is the same as v9.0, but it may have a bug in it that was fixed in v9.0. Either way, if you've found a genuine bug in v8.7, only Atlassian can confirm it and advise if it is fixed in v9.0